# The controller is not catching form POST request

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc, controller, thymeleaf

I am doing a simple project and somehow I can't "catch" the POST method call to `/collaborators/add`

I can't find the error, and maybe it is obvious (I am a newbie)...could someone please take a quick look?

**html form:**

```
<form action="/collaborators/add" method="post">
    <h2>Manage Collaborators</h2>
    <ul class="checkbox-list">
        <li th:each="c : ${collaborators}">
            <span class="primary" th:text="${c.name}">Michael Pemulius</span>
            <div class="custom-select">
                <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
                <select>
                    <option value="#" selected="selected">Designer</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="actions add-new-collaborator" th:object="${collaborator}">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name..." th:field="*{name}"/>
        <div class="custom-select">
            <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
            <select th:field="*{role}">
                <option value="#" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Role...</option>
                <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r.name}">Developer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button class="button" type="submit">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/collaborators/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addCollaborator(Model model, @Valid Collaborator collaborator, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    System.out.println("Executed");
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("but with errors");
        System.out.println(bindingResult.getFieldError());
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashMessage", new FlashMessage("The collaborator was not created", FlashMessage.Status.FAILURE));
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("collaborator", collaborator);
        return "redirect:/collaborators";
    }
    collaboratorService.save(collaborator);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashMessage", new FlashMessage("The collaborator was created", FlashMessage.Status.SUCCESS));
    return "redirect:/collaborators";
}
```

There is no error message in the console, just a 400.

I think the problem is with thymeleaf! Here:

```
<div class="custom-select">
    <span class="dropdown-arrow"></span>
    <!--<select th:field="*{role}">-->
    <select>
        <option value="#" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Role...</option>
        <!--<option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r.name}">Developer</option>-->
        <option th:each="r : ${roles}" th:value="${r}" th:text="${r.name}">Developer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I am pretty sure is an error with the object binding.

Comment: Your form Data is saved in a `Model` object, so you should pass a model to your method params and read it from there. Or use the `@ModelParameter` annotation This might be the issue. I hope that you don't try to call it with backslashes (\\) as you showed in your post. The error message would also be good. See [this guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)

Comment: try this and se if it works: remove the first `/` in form tag, i.e `action="collaborators/add"` instead of `action="/collaborators/add"`

Comment: You are right, I missed the model (and I edited the question).

I there now, but it doesn't catch the request yet...

Comment: @JackFlamp, changed and nope...

Comment: Try to run your browsers developer tools and check the network tab. What URL is is trying to POST to when you submit the form?

Comment: This:

Request URL:http://localhost:8080/collaborators/add
Request Method:POST
Status Code:400 
Remote Address:[::1]:8080
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: It is a 400 error, not a 404 one! (in case there is any difference at all).

Comment: I am pretty sure it has to do with object binding with thymeleaf!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your html a little bit.

```
<form th:action="@{/collaborators/add}" method="post" th:object="${collaborator}">
    //here you can bind all attributes inside collaborator
```

That would be all changes you need to do basically

Comment: That one was good, thanks!

So, why can't I bind the object in the <div> as I was doing?

As far as I understand, binding in the form is binding and object to a piece of code much larger that the part where it should be bound...

Why this does not work?

`<div class="actions add-new-collaborator" th:object="${collaborator}">`

Thanks!

Comment: because the attribute object only works for forms, then you can use inside inputs, select, checboxes,..but you can not bind an object into a div. Mayb you confused with render into a div a piece of code with ajax, thats true, but not for binding objects, for that, you need a form always

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, I didn't know that we need to bind objects in forms, nowhere else.

Comment: Something new you know now :) could do you validate the response as valid? then is also useful for other members? Thanks!

Comment: Sure! Thank you Cralfaro.

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify the Answer:

I was doing:

```
        <form action="/collaborators/add" method="post">
            ...
            <div class="actions add-new-collaborator" th:object="${collaborator}">
               ...
            </div>
        </form>
```

So I was binding my object in the div, which is wrong.

Objects must be bound in the form, so instead of that, do:

```
        <form th:action="@{/collaborators/add}" method="post" th:object="${collaborator}">
            ...
            <div class="actions add-new-collaborator" th:object="${collaborator}">
               ...
            </div>
        </form>
```

And it is solved!